# Android Studio - Java - Difficulty Highlighting ListView Item Background Color

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

**Introduction:**

I am encountering an issue with highlighting the background color of `ListView` items in my Android application. Despite my attempts to modify the background color programmatically, the changes are not reflected in the UI.

**Problem Description:**

I am trying to dynamically change the background color of `ListView` items based on certain conditions, such as matching a specific song name. However, even though my code executes without errors and logs indicate that the matching logic is functioning correctly, the UI does not reflect the changes. The background color remains unchanged.

Initialization of `ListView` and `Adapter`:

```
ListView songsListView = findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
SongsAdapter songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(context, songNames);
songsListView.setAdapter(songsAdapter);
```

Attempt to Change Background Color within Loop:

```
            // Find and highlight the song using the adapter
            for (int i = 0; i < songsAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                String tempSongName = songsAdapter.getItem(i);
                // Log information about the song
                Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #222 - ChildViewInfo - Child view index: " + i);
                Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #223 - ChildViewInfo - tempSongName: " + tempSongName + ", lastViewedSongName: " + (i + 1) + ") " + lastViewedSongName);
                // Check if the song name matches the last viewed song name
                if (tempSongName != null && tempSongName.equalsIgnoreCase((i + 1) + ") " + lastViewedSongName)) {
                    // Highlight the corresponding ListView item
                    View childView = songsAdapter.getView(i, null, songsListView);
                    if (childView instanceof TextView) {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) childView;
                        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        // Log the match
                        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #226 - ChildViewInfo - Match found for song: " + lastViewedSongName);
                        // Exit the loop once the match is found
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

xml:

```
<!-- list_item_song.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Song Number -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNumberTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <!-- Song Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#888888" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my `adapter` class - `SongListAdapter`:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_song, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the item for this position
        String songName = getItem(position);

        // Find views in the layout
        TextView itemNumberTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNumberTextView);
        TextView songNameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.songNameTextView);

        // Set the song number
        itemNumberTextView.setText((position + 1) + ")");

        // Set the song name
        songNameTextView.setText(songName);

        // Set background color
        int backgroundColor = mBackgroundColors.get(position, 0); // Default is transparent
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**I Have Tried:**

Trying to change the background color from the `Adapter` class:

```
    public void updateItemBackground(int position, int color) {
        mBackgroundColors.put(position, color);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

with the adapter defined at the class level:

```
private SongListAdapter adapter;`
```

and populated here:

```
adapter = new SongListAdapter(this, songNames);
```

and being used to call the `updateItemBackground` method here, from within my loop:

```
                    if (childView instanceof TextView) {
                        adapter.updateItemBackground(i, Color.YELLOW);
                        // Log the match
                        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #226 - ChildViewInfo - Match found for song: " + lastViewedSongName);
                        // Exit the loop once the match is found
                        break;
                    }
```

But I got a `NullPointerException` error - which I was able to fix via `@Upendra Shah's` comment but still cannot highlight the item within the `ListView`.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: can you add  some Logcat errors too?  NullPointerException does not clarify the error.

Comment: Thank you @smnadim21 - I just added the `Logcat` to the end of my original post.

Comment: As per logcat you are calling updateItemBackground from a null pointer means there is not getting adapter instance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Upendra Shah, you were correct in that I neglected to create an instance of the adapter which I have done just now: `adapter = new SongListAdapter(this, songNames);` which calls the method here: `adapter.updateItemBackground(i, Color.YELLOW);` however there is no background color change occurring in the `TextView` within the `ListView` - but NullPointer error is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this class level variable:

```
private List<Songs> songsList;
```

but I also had another `List` variable and was mixing the use to access my `List`. I removed the redundant object and rewrote my code to only use the `songsList` object.  By doing this I was able to isolate my object without confusing with multiple objects doing the same function.

Additionally, using this to my parent class to call the `Adapter` class (`SongListAdapter`), using this variable:

```
private SongListAdapter songsAdapter;
```

and passing into my `Adapter` class:

```
        songsAdapter = new SongListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<>());
        songsListView.setAdapter(songsAdapter);
```

I was able to call this method in my `onActivityResult` (parent class):

```
    public void updateItemBackground(int position, int color) {
        // Reset all background colors to transparent
        mBackgroundColors.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Log the reset action
        Log.d("SttList", "(UpdateBackground) Resetting background colors");

        int adjustmentFactor = 50;

        int lighterColor = Color.rgb(
                Math.min(Color.red(Color.DKGRAY) + adjustmentFactor, 255),
                Math.min(Color.green(Color.DKGRAY) + adjustmentFactor, 255),
                Math.min(Color.blue(Color.DKGRAY) + adjustmentFactor, 255)
        );

        // Set the background color of the specific item
        mBackgroundColors.put(position, lighterColor);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

These actions were able to highlight the `List` at the appropriate array index.